# Unambigious expression for ternary strings

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, regular-expressions

So I'm trying to find an unambiguous expression for M where M is the set of ternary strings where each block of 1s has length at least 3 and every block of 2s has odd length.Where ternary strings are of

```
{1,2,3}*
```

I started with the expression

```
(0*11(1)*(22)*)*
```

but found a contradiction as 11.1111 and 1111.11 can both be obtained
how can I change my expression to make it express the question above

Comment: Try $\big(0^*\lor111^*\lor22(22)^*\big)^*$. (You may use a different symbol for OR, possibly $+,\cup$, or $\mid$.)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott could you explain how this works ? I'm kind of a beginner at binary strings and combinatorics

Comment: Give me a few minutes, and I’ll write up an actual answer.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you, for being so kind!

Answer (score 1):

The final answer is very complicated, so I will need to employ some shortcuts. Introduce the following shorthand:

```
X = 0(0)*
Y = 11(1)*
Z = 22(22)*
```

These represent nonempty legal blocks of $0$s, $1$s and $2$s. Next, let

```
W = (ε + Z)Y(ZY)*(ε + Z)
```

Here, the $+$'s represent "or," while $\varepsilon$ represents the empty string. $W$ represents any legal string which only involves $1$s and $2$s, and which has at least one $1$. Now, let $A$ be an expression for a legal string which ends in $0$. You can show that

```
A = (ε + Z + W)X((W + Z)X)*
```

Then, letting $B$ represent legal strings ending in $1$, you can show

```
B = (ε + A)(ε + Z)Y(ZY)*
```

and furthermore, letting $C$ represent legal strings ending in $2$, that

```
C = (ε + A + B)Z
```

Finally, the expression you want is

```
ε + A + B + C
```

You can combine all of these substitutions to get a string involving `ε,0,1,2,+` and `*` alone, but it would be super complicated!